# Sign In with Apple - There is a problem with the request entity Domain name is invalid

Tags: apple-developer, apple-sign-in

I have found a potential bug with Sign In with Apple.

When I configure **Sign In with Apple**, under Domains and Associated Email Addresses I add the app's domain but gives me the error -

```
There is a problem with the request entity
Domain name is invalid
```

The domain is online and working with a valid SSL cert using **Let's Encrypt**.

Anyone else experiencing this issue?

Tried adding/removing the `www.` and adding a following slash `/`.

Comment: You should probably ask Apple, telling them the actual domain name that triggers this error. Without knowing what the domain name is, nobody here can even guess what's wrong.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner, unfortunately, I can't share the domain publically. I have already contacted Apple support and done searches online but found nothing on the topic.

Comment: I can fully understand that you can't disclose the domain name, but in this case Apple is really the only place you can contact.